# what is the specific number? if i use read method of BufferedReader Class

Tags: java

I wanna know exact meaning of the number returned when using the read method of BufferedReader class.. 
for example... please below code..

```
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int test=0;
        try {

            test = br.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IOTestMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println(test);
```

and then.. input "aaaa" and then I can see the Integer result "10"

What is the exact meaning of 10 ..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29)

> The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ OP is getting 10 if input is aaaa,why?He should get 97

Comment: @javaBeginner The 10 is the newline.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ if you simply press the enter key then i think 10 will be output but he is entering aaaa then also 10,hoq?

Comment: He might pressing enter after  he enters 'aaaa',I guess.

Comment: Yeap~~ originally if I input "aaa" , I can see the result 97~
but before I enters "aaaa" , I entered Just "enter" ... T.T 
Thanks for answering everyone~ ^_^